Заполночь / За полночь
В значении "когда". Как правильно?

Шёл я как-то через кладбище, было уже заполночь...

или

Шёл я как-то через кладбище, было уже за полночь...


№ 263472
Подскажите, пожалуйста значение слова - контаминация. а также правильное написание - за полночь или заполночь ??!! Спасибо
ОТВЕТ
Верно: за полночь.
